# Equivalent definitions of Sobolev space on manifold and references

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

It is well-known that there are two equivalent definitions of Sobolev space on open subset $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$:

D1. The completion of $C^\infty(\Omega)$ under $H^p_k$ norm.

D2. All functions with the $i$-times weak derivative $L^p$-integrable,  $1\leq i\leq k$.

I have already come across some representative references on Sobolev spaces on Riemannian manifolds, such as E. Hebey(1999) and T.Aubin(1982). Surprisingly, these materials only cover the first definition on Riemannian manifold $M$. Soon I realized that (D2) required the duals of those operators $\nabla^k$, thus the author had to append a huge amount of additional conceptions on differential geometry to validate it.  Maybe that's why they chose not to mention the second definition.

However, even burdened with extra work, the second definition should be working somehow. This post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126419/density-of-smooth-functions-in-sobolev-spaces-on-manifolds has provided some references, but I have no access to them.

Is there any other reference studying their relationship?

Comment: I feel embarrassed to ask exactly what is going on in the completion of $C^\infty(\Omega)$ under $H^p_k$ norm. Could you please tell me what the completion is all about? I have been having a hard time understanding the completion. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Steve It's the standard completion of a metric space.

Comment: Thank you. I have learned comletions of metric spaces from Munkres' *Topology*, but I'm not sure if the vector space $C^\infty(\Omega)$ is equipped with the $H^p_k$-norm, which makes $C^\infty(\Omega)$ into a metric space to be completed.

Comment: @Steve $C^\infty(\Omega)$ can be endowed with any kinds of norms, if it satisfies the axioms required for normed spaces.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I don't know exactly what "The completion of $C^\infty(\Omega)$ under $H^p_k$ norm" means. Munkres did not talk that way in his book.

Comment: @Steve Just the limitation of smooth functions. You can regard them as some measurable functions.

Comment: Thank you. So is the $H_k^p$-norm now defined on $C^\infty(\Omega)$ in order to make it a normed vector space?

Comment: @Steve Not "in order to", that's just how it's defined

Comment: Sorry, I still fail to grasp what you're talking about. We can complete $C^\infty(\Omega)$ only when it is made into a metric space, right? And the $H_k^p$-norm serves our need because it introduces a metric to $C^\infty(\Omega)$.

Comment: @Steve Any metric on $C^\infty$ will make it a metric space and you can talk about its completion. Only this norm $H^p_k$ will make it Sobolev space.

Comment: Exactly, that's how it is. Thank you.